# API.ai platform: How many projects are allowed in each account?

Tags: project, dialogflow-es

I created more than three projects in my account today, and saw error message with orange color. I cannot find answer for this question on the web.

Wish that API.ai can have its own bot to quickly answer all these routine Q from its users.

Any input is welcome.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the error message. The last time I checked, you can have up to 50 projects in an account. But they did make some recent changes too, but I don't expect that the number could be as small as three. The error message might be related to something else.

Comment: Thanks for this input.  The error message is " You do not have rights to do this operations " . I guess that this platform is having technical problems today. I will confirm this after I hear from API.ai team.

Comment: Nobody from API.ai have replied me here or through email since I reported this problem !!!